# Typescript: Array undefined inside a forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, foreach

I have an array that is always undefined inside a forEach, even when I initialize it before entering the forEach:

```
    this.deletedPersons =  new Array<PersonMasterBase>();

    selectedPersons.forEach(function (value) {
      let index = allPersons.findIndex(p => p.p_PersonID == value.p_PersonID);
      if (index < 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        this.deletedPersons.push(allPersons[index]);
        allPersons.splice(index, 1);
      }

    });
```

Any references I find online deal with the array that is the subject of the forEach, rather than a 'third party' as in my case.

The error occurs on the line where I push to this.deletedPersons and its text is:

```
 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deletedPersons')\n    
 at http://localhost:4200/main.js:8200:30\n    
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    
 at http://localhost:4200/main.js:8191:33\n    
 at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35305:37\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34722:21)\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33551:18)\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber.onFinalize (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34141:36)\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber.unsubscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34761:88)\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34751:26)\n    
 at OperatorSubscriber.complete (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33569:18)'
```

Comment: The forEach callback calls an Array method on `allPersons` and `this.deletedPersons`. If either isn't an array, you'll get an error. Since we can rule out `this.deletedPersons`, it's probably `allPersons`. Is it supposed to be `this.allPersons` maybe? Also please always state the error you're getting and point out the line it references.

Comment: I'v e just added that detail now

Comment: @ChrisG Don’t rule out `this.deletedPersons`…!

Comment: @deceze True, I missed it's not an arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` in forEach function is referring to the current scope(forEach) and not the class itself, so `this.deletedPersons` inside `forEach` means your are trying to access the `deletedPersons` declared in forEach which is obviously not.

the solution to this is to whether to use arrow function as:

```
selectedPersons.forEach((value) => {
      let index = allPersons.findIndex(p => p.p_PersonID == value.p_PersonID);
      if (index < 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        this.deletedPersons.push(allPersons[index]);
        allPersons.splice(index, 1);
      }

    });
```

Or assign the `this.deletedPersons` to any other variable like `allPersons` maybe `deletedPersonsList`